# Update statement in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update the records of one table using others but getting failed with the error. Can someone pls help how to fix the below query for updating records  :

ERROR: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed

```
UPDATE
    table1 t1
    set t1.field1=t2.field1
FROM
    table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON upper(t1.schemaname)=upper(t2.databasename)
 and upper(t1.tablename)=upper(t2.tablename)
and t1.field1!=t2.field1
WHERE
   t1.field1!='test'
and T2.field1  in('abc','def')
```

Comment: remove alias from table1 after update. Your starting should be like this.. UPDATE table1 set field1=t2.field1

Comment: Take a look here [Postgres update from](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: @jakbar-Yes,I have tried it still getting same issue

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k-Yes,I have tried these based on different documents but no luck.Hence asking if someone already gone through the same scenario in past.

Comment: It looks like there are some rows in `table1` which get joined to more than one row in `table2`. Then it is unclear which of the `t2.field1` should be used as the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query, works pretty well,

```
UPDATE
    table1 t1
    set t1.field1=t2.field1
FROM
    (select * from table2 where field1 in('abc','def')) t2 
    where upper(t1.schemaname)=upper(t2.databasename)
 and upper(t1.tablename)=upper(t2.tablename)
and t1.field1!=t2.field1
and  t1.field1!='test'
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim..it worked fine.I have another requirement where I need to fetch the email address from text.Example , abc-cde-ghi-abc@test.com-cde@test.com.There is no fixed position of '-' so wanted to check the best way to fetch the email out of it...output needs to be abc@test.com;cde@test.com.

Comment: I have tried substring (pg_catalog.obj_description(pgc.oid, 'pg_class'),'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}') but not sure how to fetch multiple email address.

Comment: @Ram Sure, happy to help you. Can you post this as a new question and provide the url to the question

Comment: @Jim-I don't know but for some reason, I have been restricted to post new question but I have created sample of query on fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/vbiSy1jM ,issue is query ran fine on fiddle but when I am trying to run it with thousand of records in database its throwing error : multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed.Can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-- Step 1: Create the 'table1' and 'table2' tables
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    schemaname VARCHAR(255),
    tablename VARCHAR(255),
    field1 VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    databasename VARCHAR(255),
    tablename VARCHAR(255),
    field1 VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Step 2: Insert sample data into 'table1' and 'table2'
INSERT INTO table1 (schemaname, tablename, field1) VALUES
    ('public', 'tableA', 'abc'),
    ('public', 'tableB', 'def'),
    ('public', 'tableC', 'xyz'),
    ('schema1', 'tableX', '123');

INSERT INTO table2 (databasename, tablename, field1) VALUES
    ('public', 'tableA', '123'),
    ('public', 'tableB', 'def'),
    ('public', 'tableC', 'xyz'),
    ('schema1', 'tableX', '456');

-- Step 3: Perform the update
UPDATE table1 AS t1
SET field1 = t2.field1
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE
    UPPER(t1.schemaname) = UPPER(t2.databasename)
    AND UPPER(t1.tablename) = UPPER(t2.tablename)
    AND t1.field1 != t2.field1
    AND t1.field1 != 'test'
    AND t2.field1 IN ('abc', 'def');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code this way;

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET field1 = t2.field1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE
  upper(t1.schemaname) = upper(t2.databasename)
  AND upper(t1.tablename) = upper(t2.tablename)
  AND t1.field1 != t2.field1
  AND t1.field1 != 'test'
  AND t2.field1 IN ('abc', 'def');
```